# Is it possible to replace default Windows color picker dialog?

Tags: windows-7, colors, user-interface

I am using software like text editors or development tools that use default Windows color picker dialog. Is there a way to intercept somehow calls to windows color picker dialog and show custom dialog? Does such software can exist?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the windows 10 default color picker](https://superuser.com/questions/1412770/how-to-change-the-windows-10-default-color-picker)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to intercept somehow calls to windows color picker dialog

Yes there is:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intercepting-system-api-calls

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

But intercepting common dialog functions would be exceptionally difficult.

> Does such software can exist [to intercept default Windows color picker dialog]?

It would seem that it does not. I have searched far and wide myself for something like what you're asking for (because I too would love to banish Windows' color picker for ever) but to this day I have found nothing.